# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError"

Tags: java, smartcard

This exception is arising when I am running my program for smart card reading. My device is not connected. Please help me.

Comment: Maybe it's because the device is not connected?

Comment: May be you are correct. I will try after device connection.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This means it could not load a shared library you need.  This could be because.

- The library is not in your library path.
- The library does not have the right name e.g. LIBRARY must be libLIBRARY.so on Unix
- The library is not executable by you.
- The library is not for the OS or bit size of your JVM. e.g. a 64-bit JVM will not load a 32-bit library.
- Your JRE is not installed correctly and it is failing to load one of its own libraries.
- You are using a shared library which needs another shared library you don't have.
- The DLL wasn't build as a JNI library or used from JNA.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But i am using a .dll file for read the smart card.I am just loading that dll file.

Comment: All the suggestions I made still apply.

Comment: @soljava You can't just load a dll file like that from Java. Either it must be a JNI dll or you must use JNA (or something similar if that exists...).

Comment: @maba oh, you can load it into the Java process with too much problems (if it does have all the properties that pb2q mentioned. It's communicating afterwards with it that's the trick :)

Answer (score 0):

I got this when using System.loadLibrary which will use the java.libary.path resource.
Since absolute path isn't allowed by loadLibrary, you can use the absolute path and load method.

```
    System.load(HelloWorld.class.getResource("/dlls/HelloWorld.dll")
            .getPath());
```