# Java cannot open shared object file

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

I'm just learning java, and I've been working through the activities on Programming by Doing. I was just working on compiling [this](https://programmingbydoing.com/a/using-swing-for-input.html) program, but every time I attempt to run it, terminal throws this back at me:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: /home/trenza/java/jdk1.8.0_60/jre/lib/i386/libawt_xawt.so: libXtst.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
    at java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary0(ClassLoader.java:1938)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1821)
    at java.lang.Runtime.load0(Runtime.java:809)
    at java.lang.System.load(System.java:1086)                                            
    at java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load(Native Method)                            
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary0(ClassLoader.java:1938)                          
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1842)                           
    at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:870)                                   
    at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1122)                                     
    at java.awt.Toolkit$3.run(Toolkit.java:1636)
    at java.awt.Toolkit$3.run(Toolkit.java:1634)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.awt.Toolkit.loadLibraries(Toolkit.java:1633)
    at java.awt.Toolkit.<clinit>(Toolkit.java:1668)
    at java.awt.Component.<clinit>(Component.java:593)
```

No matter what I do, I can't seem to figure out how to retrieve those missing things. I'm sure that my JDK is updated and properly installed, so I just don't know what else it could be.

Comment: Take a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17355863/cant-find-install-libxtst-so-6)! It must be an issue with the host you are on.

Comment: Have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17355863/cant-find-install-libxtst-so-6

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11825528/exception-in-thread-main-java-lang-unsatisfiedlinkerror